# Write a SQL Query in Google Big Query which pulls all values from last week, all values from 2 weeks ago, and calculate percent change between them

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query a table comparing order numbers from last week (Sunday to Saturday) vs 2 weeks ago, and calculate percent change between the two. My thought process so far has been to group my date column by week, then use a lag function to pull last week and the previous week in to the same row. From there use basic arithmetic functions to calculate percent change. In practice, I haven't been able to get a working query, but I picture the table to look as follows:

| Week | Orders | Orders - Previous Week | % Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-05 | 5 | 10 | -0.5 |
| 2023-01-29 | 10 | 2 | +5.0 |
| 2023-01-29 | 2 |  |  |

Important to note that the days in last week should not change regardless of what day it is today (i.e not use today -7 days to calculate last week, and -14 days to calculate 2 weeks ago)

My query so far:

```
SELECT 
min(date) as date,
orders,
coalesce(lag(order) over (order by (date), 0)) as Orders - Previous Week
FROM `table` 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND current_date()
group by date_trunc(date, WEEK)
ORDER BY date desc
```

I realize I'm not using coalesce and my lag function correctly, but a bit lost on how to correct it

Answer (score -4):

To calculate the percent change, you can use the following query:

```
sql
Copy code
SELECT 
  min(date) as Week,
  sum(orders) as Orders,
  coalesce(sum(lag(orders) over (order by date_trunc(date, WEEK))), 0) as "Orders - Previous Week",
  (sum(orders) - coalesce(sum(lag(orders) over (order by date_trunc(date, WEEK))), 0)) / coalesce(sum(lag(orders) over (order by date_trunc(date, WEEK))), 0) as "% Change"
FROM `table` 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND current_date()
group by date_trunc(date, WEEK)
ORDER BY Week desc
```

In this query, the sum function is used to aggregate the orders by week. The coalesce function is used to handle the case where there is no previous week data, and default to 0. The percent change calculation uses the same formula you described.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. When using this query, I get an error on the coalesce function stating that Analytic functions cannot be arguments to aggregate functions

Comment: Wah @Atom well be careful with ChatGPT!